# Angular Form validation submit button not disabling properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a simple 2 input form using Angular Material form field with error handling. I have a FormControl on each of the input fields. The errors show up properly if there are no values entered for the fields.

However the submit button is never disabled, even when the fields are both empty.

Can anybody see that the problem might be?

Here is my HTML

```html
    <form class="add-dialog-form" (ngSubmit)="onAddField()" #addField="ngForm">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter name" [formControl]="name" required name="name">
        <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">{{getNameErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter value" [formControl]="value" required name="value">
        <mat-error *ngIf="value.invalid">{{getValueErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div mat-dialog-actions class="dialog-button-align">
        <button mat-button (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="!addField.form.valid">Add Field</button>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Here is how I have defined the FormControl and the error message handling for it in the component, as per the Angular Material example:

```js
    name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    value = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);

    getNameErrorMessage() {
      return this.name.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
    }

    getValueErrorMessage() {
      return this.value.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `addField` in your typescript

Comment: also since your using a form tag, id recommend just making a form group.

Comment: I think it is just `addField.valid` or `addField.invalid`.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil That didn't work...